Данные какого типа будут одинаково представлены и в текстовом, и в двоичном файлах?
Вопрос, который мне задала преподователь, нигде не могу найти ответ.

ну, да, для начала надо пояснить, что же это за такие звери - «текстовый и двоичный файлы». // а «троичные» и «четверичные» бывают?

@aleksandrbarakin подразумеваются бинарные файлы

А двоичный файл мы как смотрим? )  Если смотреть 16-ричные числа в двоичном файле в 16-ричном представлении, то они вполне себе будут выглядеть практически как и в текстовый файл их вывести подряд. Но так то конечно текст, хотя опять же смотря какой.

Тут еще надо разобраться, что именно ваш преподаватель вообще называет файлом (и как она отличает текстовый от двоичного)

@avp, $ file temp.c -> temp.c: C source, ASCII text.  $ file a.out -> a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ....

Честно говоря, минусовать этот вопрос не правильно. Это вопрос. Он имеет смысл. На него трудно ответить. Почему минус?

@StanislavVolodarskiy, да, согласен, вопрос не простой (я плюсанул). Вроде интуитивно ясен, но нюансов полно. Начиная с того, имеется в виду набор данных на носителе или это данные, которые в некоторой ОС поступают в память программы и становятся доступны для каких-то операций с ними. Если вспомнить историю, то наверное правильный текстовый файл это тот, который можно послать на принтер и увидеть его на печати без искажений. Но тут опять же -- а какой именно принтер (с тех пор их такой зоопарк развелся...)

Текст в двоичном файле представляется также как в текстовом.
В принципе, можно пойти дальше и определить текст как данные, которые одинаково представляются в двоичном и текстовом форматах.

да что ж это за «форматы» такие? («в двоичном и текстовом форматах»). чем же отличаются два идентичных набора байтов, будучи помещёнными в эти два как бы разных фйла?

Или все же внутри файла все данные будут одинаковы, а вот используемое приложение ...

@aleksandrbarakin, внутри скомпилированного модуля можно отыскать строковые константы. Скомпилированая программа обычно воспринимается как двоичный файл. Внутри него есть тексты из исходного кода. Я не хочу (или не могу, не знаю пока) всё это формализовывать, но на бытовом уровне текстовые файлы отличаются от нетекстовых.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, если в файл записать два байта a\n - какой у файла будет «формат»?

@aleksandrbarakin, не могу формализовать полностью. Но, например, утилита file в Linux анализирует содержимое файла и принимает решение текст/не текст. То есть, какое-то общепринятое понятие есть. Типизация на уровне ОС.
